# Entering as a tourist after French student visa

Tags: schengen-visas, study, long-stay-visas, 90-180-visa-rules

I am a US citizen. I just finished a French visa type D VLS-T "long séjour temporaire" student visa on February 27. I returned to the US and got an exit stamp.

I want to return to France (to visit friends) for 70 days starting April 1. I want to confirm that the 90/180 rules did not apply while I had a type D visa, even though it was a VLS-T not a VLS-TS. I think this is in article 6 of the schengen borders code.

I want to confirm this, but the French consulate is being vague and I'd really like a more clear answer as to how/why this is possible. Additionally, I am worried that a VLS-T may not have the same rights as a VLS-TS.

****if anybody is wondering I got into the country no problem

Comment: After a fall semester in Spain (on a student visa) my daughter traveled back for a few weeks in the spring (US passport, no visa) without issues. The 70 days may raise a few eyebrows though, so your mileage may vary.